# Is there any file size limitation on reading a file of type TextFile (using Readln and/or Read)?

Tags: delphi

Is there any file size limitation on reading a file of type TextFile (using Readln and/or Read)? For example, 2gb (max integer)?

Comment: What Delphi version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such limitations.